# Ruby - Converting text file to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm very new to Ruby on Rails and am using it to augment some C++ code. My C++ code currently outputs data from a multi-dimensional array to a text file like such:

```
2 2 2 2 2 3 1 1 1 1 5 2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 2 2 2 
2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 
2 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 2 
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 
3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
6 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 
2 6 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 2 
2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 
2 2 2 6 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2 6 1 1 1 1 4 2 2 2 2 2
```

I'm looking for help in converting this text output into a two-dimensional array for Ruby input with dynamic height/width.
So far I've been inputting them by hand into my Ruby code but will soon be doing a lot more tests and I haven't been able to find a way to convert this into a two-dimensional Ruby array so far. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
File.foreach('file.txt').map { |line| line.split(' ') }
```

Answer (score 11):

```
File.readlines('foo.txt').map &:split
```

Comment: Alternatively, `File.read('foo.txt').lines.map &:split`. Just because.